# Probability to win.

Tags: probability

Two players $A$ and $B$ are playing the final of chess championship which contains a series of matches.

The probability that $A$ wins is ${2\over 3}$.

The probability that $B$ wins is ${1\over 3}$.

The winner will be the one who is 
ahead by 2 games as compared to the
other and wins at least 6 games.

If the player $B$ wins the first 4 matches, 
find the probability that $A$ wins the championship.

My attempt:

We should find the following probabilities:

$A$ wins 6 matches given $B$ has won the first 4.
$A$ wins 7 matches given $B$ has won the 
first 4 and wins one out of the next 8.

But I am not getting any patterns.

Comment: Realize that this championship can last "forever" because A and B can keep on winning alternatively after B has won first 4. This looks to me like a Markov chain with 2 attractors: A wins or B wins. You need a sketch with all possible "states" for this structure

Comment: Yes I think we should get an infinite GP but that's not happening.

Comment: do you know how to do this if it is 0-0 and the 6 win caveat does not apply?  Eventually the match has to boil down to a 0-0, 1-0 or 0-1 situation

Comment: The number of possibilities is more than it seems like. I worked it out partially, but my classes are coming up now. In theory, this problem falls typically within the scope of Absorbing Markov chains and once that matrix has ben set up, it becomes straight forward. But in your problem, too many states to consider.

Comment: A on 4 is a critical point, - the routes to 4-4 or 4-5 can be simplified - if B wins, then A has to win until he is on 5, or he lost, if A wins a game, then B winning a game creates a similar situation as before- if it gets to 4-4, then it is effectively 0-0 - so we can only have 5 games before A is on 4, or B won

Comment: you need the probability that the A-B score becomes 4-4 or 4-5 (with otherwise B won) then for each of these you need the probability of winning where the A-B score is 0-1 and 0-0 - once A has 4, the 6 win rule has become irrelevant, and it is only the lead of 2 that both seek

Comment: I reread the question and I have another doubt, don't you think B already won? Or do the given conditions apply after B has one the first 4 matches

Comment: But then A should win 3 matches and B 1 with n number of matches won by both of them.

Comment: Why aren't draws considered here? They are allowed and pretty common in chess.

Comment: @tmm - the text of the question simply precludes draws, they don't need to be considered - one way of fitting the question to the real world is to say that draws are ignored, they are classed as 0-0 - we are only counting wins - it would be better to have made a question with no draws, e.g. Badminton

Comment: @amit - in the next 5 games, A has to win 4 or 5 of the games - that guarantees he is still in the match - if A does not win either 4 or 5 of the next 5 games, then it has to be that he lost 2  games, and at some point was trailing to 6 points, and did not have 5 wins himself - those two cases include all posibilities that lead to either A loses, 5-4 or 4-5

Answer (score 5):

Go ahead and play another $6$ games, *even if the ultimate winner is decided before all six games have been played*.  If player A wins all six of these games, which happens with probability $(2/3)^6$, he is the champion at that point (having won two more games than player B's four wins).  If player A wins five of the six, which happens with probability $6(2/3)^5(1/3)$, the contest at this point is a tie, to which we'll return.  Finally, if player A wins four or fewer of the next six games, then player B is the champion (because she will have won at least two games, bringer her to six wins, which will be at least two more than player A).

So let's see what player A's chances become when starting from a tie.  Call this $p$.  We know we have to play at least two more games.  Either player A wins them both, which happens with probability $(2/3)^2$, or they split wins, leaving them tied again, which happens with probability $2(2/3)(1/3)$, or else A loses.  Thus

$$p=\left(2\over3\right)^2+2\left(2\over3\right)\left(1\over3\right)p={4\over9}(1+p)$$

from which we find $p=4/5$.  In total, the probability that player A wins the championship is

$$\left(2\over3\right)^6+6\left(2\over3\right)^5\left(1\over3\right)\left(4\over5\right)=\left(2\over3\right)^5{34\over15}={1088\over3645}\approx0.2985$$

**Remark**:  A key point to understand in this approach is that allowing "meaningless" games to be played does not affect the answer, but simplifies some of the analysis.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.

Comment: Go ahead and play another 6 games, even if the ultimate winner is decided before all six games have been played.Can you explain about this statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Markov chain with states $0-4,1-4,2-4,3-4,0-5,1-5,2-5,3-5,0,-1,+1$ where $0$ represents a tie in the number of games with each having won at least $4$ so two wins will win the match.  $+1$ is the case that B has won one more game and has won at least $5$ and $-1$ is the case that A has won one more game and has won at least $5$.  You can start to find B's chance to win from $0,-1,+1$ by the usual technique, then work backwards for the other cases.

Comment: But I don't know about Markov chains.

Comment: I would like to understand this method too could you explain?

Comment: Each state is a possible state of the match.  With each one you associate the chance B wins from that state.  Barry Cipra has dealt with $0$.  From $+1$ you have B winning the next game and winning the match with probability $1/3$ and going to $0$ with probability $2/3$, so B's chance from $+1$ is $\frac 13 \cdot 1 + \frac 23 \cdot (1-p)$.  You can keep going to get the chance B wins from $0-4$.

Answer (score 1):

First consider the next 5 games, for B to fail to win, A must win 4 or more of the next 5 games, leaving the A-B score at 5-4 or 4-5

ok, so you should be able to work out the probability of after 5 games

1) A wins all to lead 5-4

2) A wins 4 of 5 to trail 4-5

3) the compliment of 1 & 2 is that neither of those happened, i.e. P3  = 1 - P1 - P2 and in that case B won - but you don't need all the combinations, 1 & 2 are easier to calculate

can you calculate 1 & 2?

so then the 6 win rule ceases to matter, let's say A is winning 5-4, we might as well call that +1

let's say what are the chances of A winning at -1, 0 and +1

P(-1) = (2/3)P(0) + 0 = (2/3)P(0)

A has a 2/3 chance of getting to a situation 0, and a 1/3 chance of losing completely

P(0) = (2/3)P(1) + (1/3)P(-1)

P(1) = 2/3 + (1/3)P(0)

so then you can change this all into terms of P(0) by substitutiong into the middle expression - you can then get P(0), P(-1) and P(1)

you can then multiply P(-1) and P(1) by the probabilities we worked out for the lead of 1 or -1 after 5 games